# lvalue required as left operand of assignment? Looking at other threads hasn't helped

Tags: c++, assignment-operator

```
for (i = 0 ;  i >= 0 ; i++)
{
    (j-1) = text.find("." , j) ;
    letter = static_cast <int> ( text.at(j+1) ) ;
    if (( letter < 123 ) && ( letter > 96 ))
    {
        letter = (letter - 32) ;
        letter = text.at(j+1) ;
        if ((text.find("." , j) < 0))
        {
            j = 0 ;
            break ;
        }
```

This is the code I currently have, and through trial and error i've concluded that this is the problem section. The problem that keeps occurring is listed in the title. Can anyone lend a hand? Thanks.

Comment: `(j-1) = text.find("." , j) ;` ? BTW, please format your code..

Comment: Here is the problem: `(j-1) = ...`

Comment: Yeah, I should've mentioned that, my bad.

Comment: What do you think `(j-1) =` means?

Comment: Somewhere is there you try to assign to an rvalue, possibly a temporary.

Comment: Is this meant to be an infinite loop? `for (i = 0 ;  i >= 0 ; i++)`

Comment: I'm pretty sure this is illegal:   (j-1) =

Comment: @devnull: it's basically while(true) - at least semantically. :)

Comment: I think, according to you `x=x+1` implies `0=1` :P

Answer (score 2):

You wrote:

```
(j-1) = text.find("." , j) ;
```

You cannot assign a value to `j-i`. If you want to set the value of `j` so that `j-1` is equal to something you have to add +1 on both sides of the assignment:

```
j = text.find("." , j) + 1;
```

Comment: That works, I'm unfamiliar with the intricacies of the syntax at the moment. I just assumed that they were the same (mathematically speaking they basically are)

Comment: @user2779581 Programming in C++ isn't mathematics. A variable assignment isn't defining a mathematical equivalence, it's moving a value into a slot. `(j-1)` isn't a slot, so you can't move anything there.

Comment: Unfortunately `=` does not mean the same thing in C++ as in mathematics: it does not signal equality but a variable assignment. For example you can write `j = 1; j = 2;` and it's not a contradiction; it just sets the value of the variable `j` first to 1 and then to 2. This is why `(j-1)=something` is probably illegal: `j-1` is not a variable (technically, "lvalue") and its value can only be computed, not set.